# Functional equation: finding all pairs of functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f$ strictly increasing and $ f(xy) = g(y)f(x) + f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all pairs of functions $ f,g : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> (a) if $ x < y$, then $ f(x) < f(y)$;
> (b) for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $ f(xy) = g(y)f(x) + f(y)$.

**My work :**

Let $ P(x,y) : f(xy) = g(y)f(x) + f(y)$

$x<y \iff f(x) < f(y)$

$ P(x,1) : f(x)\big(1-g(1)\big) = f(1)$

$g(1) = 1 \implies f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$

so $f(1) = f(1) + f(1) \implies f(1) = 0$

$ P(x,1) :$

$f(1) = 0 \implies f(x) = g(1)f(x)f(1)$

so $f(x)\big(1-g(1)\big) = 0 \implies g(1) = 1$

Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is, $(f,g)$ satisfies $g=\text{sgn}(x)\exp({b\log|x|})$ and $f(x)=a(g(x)-1)$ for some real numbers $a>0$ and $b>0$.

It is easy to see that all such $(f,g)$ satisfy the conditions. We will show that they are the only possibilities.

The proof is the following:

Take $y=1$, we get
$$f(x)=g(1)f(x)+f(1).$$
Since $f$ is not constant, $f(1)=0$, $g(1)=1$.

Take $y=0$,
$$
f(0)=g(0)f(x)+f(0).
$$
Hence $g(0)=0$.

Take $x=0$
$$
f(0)=g(y)f(0)+f(y),
$$
Hence $$f(x)=a(g(x)-1),$$ here we assume $f(0)=-a.$ Of course $a>-f(1)=0$ by assumption, and $g$ is monotonic increasing as $f$ is.

Use this equation to the original one, we get
$$
g(xy)=g(x)g(y).
$$
Take $x=y=-1$, note that $g$ is monotonic, hence $g(-1)=1$.
Take $y=-1$, we know that $g$ is an odd function. It is enough to show that
$g=\exp({b\log x})$ for $x>0$. This is actually a standard Cauchy functional equation problem.

Take $G(x)=\log (g(e^x))$. Note that it is well defined because $g(y)>0$ if $y>0$. Also note that $G$ is monotonic increasing and 
$$
G(x+y)=G(x)+G(y).
$$
Hence $G(x)=bx$ for some $b>0$ and we finished the proof.

Comment: However your answer and mine are same. Did you aware $g=sgn(x)\exp (b\log|x|)=x^b$?

Comment: If your b is even, what happens? Then nothing is written, though.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki In my answer, b can be any positive real number.

Comment: So, b of your answer is never even as you say.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki, it could be even, as it is well-known that, an even number is a real number.

Comment: Your answer is same with me, and $y=a(x^2-1)$ doesn't satisfly condition (a).

Comment: @TakahiroWaki No, my answer is not the same with yours. Mine is correct.

Comment: Well, rip off of my answer?

Comment: Thank you all. I'm beginner, I'm not acquainted with this form " exp(b log|x|)", will you please explain what it means ?

Comment: @carat See my comment. It means $|x|^b$. So I said, Chen Jiang.

Comment: I got it now, thank you everyone.